# JRuby UTF-8 templates and Mongo

Tags: utf-8, mongoid, jruby, slim-lang

I tried to run my rails project on jruby 1.6.7 in 1.9 mode.
I've got troubles with encodings in slim templates and mongodb (with mongoid)
template:

`incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and US-ASCII`

and in mongo I see something like Ð\u0090Ð»ÐµÐºÑ\u0081Ð°Ð½Ð´Ñ\u0080

I've tried to solve thus problem by adding in `Application.rb`

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

also I've put

```
$KCODE = 'u'
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::ASCII_8BIT
```

I've trying to put

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

in templates.

Even trying to add in `JRUBY_OPTS`

```
-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

this all does not helped.

Comment: This data are insert by mongoid or not?

Answer (score 1):

I use **jRuby 1.7.0.preview1** on **Heroku** and I had problem that all my responses ware **us-ascii** encoded. So I added following configuration to "JRUBY_OPTS". And it helps - my code returns UTF-8 responses.

```
JRUBY_OPTS:  --1.9 -J-Xmx400m -J-Dfile.encoding=utf8
```